# Run python in Windows OS installed in micro SD card which is read by Arduino microcontroller board

Tags: arduino-uno, sd-card, python, windows

I have a python code which runs in my computer with Windows operating system. The code reads some images as input, extends some cognitive services apis from Microsoft azure and finally give an audio output. I would like to run this code on an independent device, for which I am thinking to have a motherboard like Arduino (I can use raspberry pi, but it's a small project and I don't want to invest that much). However being an amateur in this genre, I have some questions and would really like if someone could help.

I want the system to have an independent processing power, with the operating system loaded in a micro SD card. I do not want to connect  Arduino with my pc and run the code from there. It will not make any sense since the PC/laptop is already able to do the work, what would I need Arduino for?

Can someone please tell me if it is possible to have an operating system installed in a micro SD card (bootable) and have it inserted in the Arduino board so that I can run the python code within the SD card?

Comment: please delete the first two paragraphs of your question because they are just fluff and they confuse the issue. ... your real question is the last paragraph only .... also remove the reference to windows OS in the title.

Answer (score 2):

With some Arduino boards, yes.  You want a board like the Yun (unfortunately retired now, but there are probably others similar) which has a MIPS SoC on it that runs Linux (specifically OpenWRT).  The OS is installed into the SoC, but there is an SD card slot that will allow you to read your code.

An alternative is a Yun shield (available from third parties, such as the [Dragino Yun Shield](http://www.dragino.com/products/yunshield/item/86-yun-shield.html)).  This turns any Uno-like Arduino into a Yun.   Of course, you can run it without any Arduino attached if you so wish to wire it manually.

However, with all these, you're getting into the price bracket of a Raspberry Pi, so you may as well do it properly and just get a Raspberry.